# Spring 5.0.5 @Value doesn't resolve to correct type

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-config, spring-properties

I'm getting the following error in spring 5, and have read all of the posts regarding this issue with no luck. I just refactored the app to use the @Configuration via the PropertiesConfig class instead of appliationContext.xml for the property placeholder definitions

```
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'secureExpirationHours'; nested 
exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert 
value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; nested exception is 
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${asset.href.expiration.hours.secure}
```

Referencing the var:

```
public class TestRepository {
    @Value("${asset.href.expiration.hours.secure}")
    private int secureExpirationHours;
}
```

Mixed Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@Import({PropertiesConfig.class})
@ImportResource({
    "classpath:META-INF/spring/applicationContext-assets.xml",
    "classpath:META-INF/spring/applicationContext-mongo.xml",
    "classpath:META-INF/spring/applicationContext-security.xml",
    "classpath:META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml"})
public class CoreConfig {
}
```

PropertiesConfig.class:

```
@Configuration
public class PropertiesConfig {

    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer commonEnvConfig;

    @Bean(name="commonConfig")
    public static PropertiesFactoryBean commonConfig() {
        PropertiesFactoryBean commonConfig = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
        commonConfig.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("META-INF/spring/config.properties"));
        return commonConfig;
    }

    @Bean(name="envProperties")
    public static YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yamlProperties() {
          YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yaml = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
          yaml.setResources(new ClassPathResource("application-dev.yaml"));
          return yaml;
    }

    @Bean(name="commonConfigPropertyPlaceholder")
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer commonConfigPropertyPlaceholder() throws IOException {
        if (commonEnvConfig == null) {
            commonEnvConfig = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        }

        PropertiesFactoryBean commonConfig = PropertiesConfig.commonConfig();
        try {
            commonEnvConfig.setProperties(commonConfig.getObject());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }

        YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yaml = PropertiesConfig.yamlProperties();
        commonEnvConfig.setProperties(yaml.getObject());
        commonEnvConfig.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);

        return commonEnvConfig;
    }
}
```

Please and thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you able to see if all resources are loaded in `PropertiesConfig` at server startup

Comment: Set `ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders` to `false` and you will probably will be greeted with an exception stating that the property cannot be found.

Comment: are you sure your property _asset.href.expiration.hours.secure_ is a **int**

Comment: After setting ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders to true, it did tell me that a different property cannot be found - indicating that there is an issue with configuration. When I change the code to only setProperties once, it works - so setting the properties twice is overriding the first set of properties. How can I configure the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer to add multiple hierarchical properties in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem(s) - there are two.

First off, you must call .afterPropertiesSet(); on the PropertiesFactoryBean, otherwise the .getObject() returns null.

```
@Bean(name="commonConfig")
public static PropertiesFactoryBean commonConfig() throws IOException {
    PropertiesFactoryBean commonConfig = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
    commonConfig.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("META-INF/spring/config.properties"));
    try {
        commonConfig.afterPropertiesSet();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
    return commonConfig;
}
```

Second, you must call "setPropertiesArray()" on the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer with both of the properties:

```
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer commonEnvConfig = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    commonEnvConfig.setPropertiesArray(commonConfig().getObject(), yamlProperties().getObject());
```